# Autocomplete code location issue

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, location

I am using the ui autocomplete plugin and all is fine except for the fact that the code gets inserted into the "body" and I need it to be located under another class.

*snip* stupid editor.

I am using the basic jquery ui autocomplete plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/  but it inserts the code at the bottom of the body.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: it might be a bit easier to work out the cause if we could see some code

Comment: Have you got a link to the autocomplete plugin? What does the API say about the snippet (which isn't in the question at the moment)?

Comment: Please apply some formatting.  What you've posted is pretty incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're asking.
You build a jQuery UI autocomplete around a textbox:

```
<input id="project" />
```

You can place your tag wherever you want, basically.
and then you have to create the autocomplete with jQuery:

```
$("#project").autocomplete();
```

I've prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/jjCvf/1/) for you.

Or you can run this:

```js
var projects = [{
  value: "jquery",
  label: "jQuery",
  desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
  icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
}, {
  value: "jquery-ui",
  label: "jQuery UI",
  desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
  icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
}, {
  value: "sizzlejs",
  label: "Sizzle JS",
  desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
  icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
}];

$("#project").autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: projects,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.desc);

    return false;
  }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
  return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

```css
#myDiv {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv">
  <label for="project">projects (j to see results):</label>
  <input id="project" />
</div>
```

Comment: Turns out I needed to change the appendTo option, doh thanks all.